# Process communication in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

What is the best way to establish communication between two processes in python? After some googling, I tried to do so:

```
parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
p = Process(target = instance_tuple.instance.run(), \
    args = (parent_pipe, child_pipe,))
p.start()
```

Sending data to the child process:

```
command = Command(command_name, args)
parent_pipe.send(command)
```

Process target function:

```
while True:
    if (self.parent_pipe.poll()):
        command = parent_pipe.recv()
        if (command.name == 'init_model'):
            self.init_model()
        elif (command.name == 'get_tree'):
            tree = self.get_fidesys_tree(*command.args)
            result = CommandResult(command.name, tree)
            self.child_pipe.send(result)
        elif(command.name == 'set_variable'):
            name = command.args[0]
            value = command.args[1]
            self.config[name] = value
```

But it doesn't seem to work (child process doesn't receive anything through `parent_pipe`). How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check parent_pipe.  Is it ever getting instantiated?

Comment: @krs1 Yes, both in child and parent processes pipes are instantiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look here : http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes
The solution is close to yours but seems easier.

Comment: The thing is that this solution doesn't work for me for some reason. I can't read anything from the pipe although data is sent.

Comment: I guess the problem is with your instantiation of the process. The parameter `target` is use to link a function to an end of the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the documentation, in child process you should read from the child part of the pipe.

```
# Process Target function

while True:
        # poll(None) because you don't want to go through the loop fast between commands
        if (self.child_pipe.poll(None)):    
            command = child_pipe.recv()
            if (command.name == 'init_model'):
                self.init_model()
            elif (command.name == 'get_tree'):
                tree = self.get_fidesys_tree(*command.args)
                result = CommandResult(command.name, tree)
                self.child_pipe.send(result)
            elif(command.name == 'set_variable'):
                name = command.args[0]
                value = command.args[1]
                self.config[name] = value
```