# Python - Using multiprocessing and pressed key detection

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I am having problems using Process from multiprocessing module. Before I used to create a Thread instead and everything worked fine, unfortunately, I had to change to optimise performance.

This is my code to play a game, it basically uses computer vision for object detection and by using a separate Process allows the game to be started.

```
#opecv infinite loop for frames processing
while True: 

# detect object, code omitted

k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF

    # when user press key 's' start the game
    if (k == ord('s') or k == ord('S')) and start is False:
        start = True
        info = False
        # # t = Thread(target=playGame, args=(k,))
        # # t = Thread(target=playGame)
        # # t.start() with threads worked successfully
        p = Process(target=playGame)
        p.start()

    # if user press 'p' capture marker position and set boolean flag to true
    elif k == ord('p') or k == ord('P'):
        waitForUserMove = True
```

---

This is my `playGame()` function containing the game loop:

```
def playGame():
    #omitted code
    while gameIsPlaying:
          getUserMove()         

    #rest of code
```

---

And finally this is my `getUserMove()` function containing a while loop to wait for the user to make the move:

```
def getUserMove():
    while waitForUserMove is False:
        pass
```

So basically when the user makes the move and press key 'p', it changes the boolean flag `waitForUserMove` to `True` and automatically breaks from the while loop, executing the rest of the code.

As I said before using Threads everything worked fine, now that I substitute Processes with Threads I am having this problem, where the boolean flag `waitForUserMove` changes to true, but this information cannot be received by the Process for some reasons.

In other words, once user press key 'p' changes the boolean flag `waitForUserMove` to `True` just outside the Process, inside the Process this `waitForUserMove` is still `False`.

So how can I do to send this info to the Process in order to change the flag `waitForUserMove` from `False` to `True`?

I hope is clear, I couldn't find better words to write my problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process communication in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109672/process-communication-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing is fundamentally different from threads. In multiprocessing the two processes have a separate memory address space so if one process writes into his memory, the sibling process can't see the change of the variable.

To exchange data between different processes you should refer to [Exchanging Objects Between Processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

In your case you only have a one way communication so Queues should work:

Setting up the queue:

```
q = Queue()
p = Process(target=playGame, args=(q,))
```

Sending in playGame:

```
def playGame(q):
    #omitted code
    while gameIsPlaying:
        move = getUserMove()
        q.put(move)
```

Receive in the main process:

```
def getUserMove():
    move = q.get()
```

Note that `q.get()` is blocking, that means the main process is blocked until `playGame` adds something into the queue. If you need to do something alongside, then use `q.get_nowait()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already looked at the Python documentation using Queue and Pipes, however none of them worked for me. It is obviously my problem. What do you think which of them should I use for my specific case? Better Pipes or Queue?

Comment: @LDG Queue is enough, since you only need a one way communication. I added some example code, is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was doing the exact same thing but not storing `q.get()` to the variable needed.