# How can I determine that values in multiprocessing.shared_memory were changed?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I would like to know. How can I determine that values in shared memory were changed? For example. I have this code.

```
import array
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, shared_memory, Manager

def process_1():
    buffer = shared_memory.ShareableList(range(5), name='AAA')
    time.sleep(1)
    buffer[1] = 100


def process_2():
    buffer = shared_memory.ShareableList(name='AAA')
    print(buffer[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_1 = Process(target=process_1)
    p_1.start()
    p_2 = Process(target=process_2)
    p_2.start()
    p_1.join()
```

How process_2 can determine that process_1 change value in buffer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109672/process-communication-in-python)

Comment: There are many possibilities. p1 can communicate to p2 that it has changed the value, or p2 can remember the old value and compare it with the current value to see if it has changed.

Comment: I'd like to get the best performance. Ideal for me would be some kind of named event. Where each process connects to an event through a name. But how it realize?